# Why function fun is not qualified for ADL?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, argument-dependent-lookup

I have simple `namespace`, which has one variable and one function. In `main` I try to call function without namespace qualifier, and variable with namespace qualifier.

```
namespace SAM
{
    int p = 10;
    void fun(int)
    {
        cout<<"Fun gets called";
    }
} 

int main()
{

    fun(SAM::p);//why SAM::fun is not get called?
    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to call fun, why it is not qualified for ADL (Argument-dependant name lookup)?

I am getting following error in Visual Studio.

> 'fun': identifier not found

If I use `SAM::fun`, it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ADL is adopted for *type*, not *variable*, e.g.

```
namespace SAM
{
    struct P {};
    void fun(P)
    {
        cout<<"Fun gets called";
    }
} 

int main()
{
    SAM::P p;
    fun(p);
    return 0;
}
```

> In the C++ programming language, argument-dependent lookup (ADL), or
>   argument-dependent name lookup, applies to the lookup of an
>   unqualified function name depending on the types of the arguments
>   given to the function call.

Reference: [Argument-dependent name lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup)